# How to scrape a _private_ google group?

Tags: ruby, authentication, screen-scraping, wget, google-groups

I'd like to scrape the discussion list of a private google group. It's a multi-page list and I might have to this later again so scripting sounds like the way to go.

Since this is a private group, I need to login in my google account first.
Unfortunately I can't manage to login using wget or ruby Net::HTTP. Surprisingly google groups is not accessible with the [Client Login interface](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html), so all the code samples are useless.

My ruby script is embedded at the end of the post. The response to the authentication query  is a 200-OK but no cookies in the response headers and the body contains the message "Your browser's cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on."

I got the same output with wget. See the bash script at the end of this message.

I don't know how to workaround this. am I missing something? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

John

Here is the ruby script:

```
# a ruby script
require 'net/https'

http = Net::HTTP.new('www.google.com', 443)
http.use_ssl = true
path = '/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth'


email='john@gmail.com'
password='topsecret'

# form inputs from the login page
data = "Email=#{email}&Passwd=#{password}&dsh=7379491738180116079&GALX=irvvmW0Z-zI"
headers =  { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'user-agent' => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0"}

# Post the request and print out the response to retrieve our authentication token
resp, data = http.post(path, data, headers)
puts resp
resp.each {|h, v| puts h+'='+v}

#warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
```

Here is the bash script:

```
# A bash script for wget
CMD=""
CMD="$CMD --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.tmp"
CMD="$CMD --no-check-certificate"
CMD="$CMD --post-data='Email=john@gmail.com&Passwd=topsecret&dsh=-8408553335275857936&GALX=irvvmW0Z-zI'"
CMD="$CMD --user-agent='Mozilla'"
CMD="$CMD https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth"
echo $CMD
wget $CMD
wget --load-cookies="cookies.tmp" http://groups.google.com/group/mygroup/topics?tsc=2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried with [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) for ruby?
Mechanize library is used for automating interaction with website; you could log in to google and browse your private google group saving what you need.

[Here](http://weare.buildingsky.net/2007/02/14/scraping-gmail-with-mechanize-and-hpricot) an example where mechanize is used for gmail scraping.

Comment: Hi systempuntoout,

thanks for your answer. I didn't know Mechanize. I managed to log in and scrape some pages, so that's great. I'll share the script later. Thanks again,

John

Comment: thanks for that link! you can basically surf the web with irb and a mechanize object!

Answer (score 1):

I did this previously by logging in manually with Firefox and then used [Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/) to automate browsing and scraping.

Comment: Chickenfoot looks very useful too. One nice plugin in my toolbox! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found this PHP Solution to [scraping private Google Groups](http://blog.gorillalogic.com/2010/03/28/scraping-google-groups/).

Comment: Thanks for the link Profjim. However my issue was to handle the google groups login. Scraping public groups is ok.